# How to have iOS app communicate with database server?

Tags: ios, web-services, asmx, asp.net-web-api

I have a database on a database server. No web service in place to be consumed by a web application.

If I want my iOS app to communicate with a database server (send & receive data), I know I can create a web service and then call that service from my iOS app. But what web service is recommended for this? Should I just write a .asmx web service in .NET or should I go for MVC WEB API or may be go for WCF ?? I have spend hours doing research on this. Please help.

Comment: Unless Apple has its own implementation of WCF, I'm fairly sure that this avenue is a no-go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot will depend on where you expect the service to be hosted, and what technology stack(s) are supported by the host. If you are self-hosting, then do whatever works in the technologies you know and understand. If you want to use a host that targets its services to small-to-midsize independent development teams, many providers like Heroku support things like Rails services. PHP is always an option as well. Microsoft-based solutions and Java-based solutions tend to be more widely used in larger enterprises and data centers, and if that's where you'll host your service then these would also be good options. And of course I'm speaking in broad generalities here: For any general trends I might list here there are lots of exceptions where other approaches make sense.

If you'd rather let the decision be driven by what makes things easiest for your iOS code, I would recommend you start with server-side technologies that support REST-ful interfaces using JSON to represent your service's resources. REST-ful services are very easy to consume from iOS, and JSON-based representations of resources are very easy to parse and produce in Objective-C.

I am personally used this approach to set a direction for my app. For the service side, I am going with a Rails implementation of REST-ful web services. I'm a Java developer by profession, but for a small independent project the options for hosting Java services were more limiting than with Rails so I've picked up rails on the side to make my project work. So far it's suited my project quite well.